# Using XPaths within a Loop C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I currently have a piece of code that adds items into a bag with a 200 limit. But instead of having this limit in place i want to introduce a loop which will keep adding items until 200 is reached.

The issue i'm having is i'm not sure how i'd incorporate XPaths within my loop

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Threading;

namespace Exercise1
{
    class Mock1
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.asos.com/men/");
            webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input[@data-testid='search-input']")).SendKeys("nike trainers");
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@data-testid='search-button-inline']")).Click();



            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            IWebElement country = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("article img")));
            webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("article img")).Click();

            IWebElement Size = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//select[@data-id='sizeSelect']"));
            SelectElementFromDropDown(Size, "UK 10 - EU 45 - US 11");

            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-bind='text: buttonText']")).Click();

            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//span[text()='Added']")));
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@data-testid='bagIcon']")).Click();
```

// I want to introduce a loop from here so that when item is added to the bag it keeps looping till 200 is reached.

```
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//select[contains(@class,'bag-item-quantity')]")));

            string totalPrice = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='bag-subtotal-price']")).Text;

            double pricePerItem = Convert.ToDouble(totalPrice.Substring(1));


            int priceLimit = 200;

            double noOfQuantity = priceLimit / pricePerItem;

            IWebElement qty = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[contains(@class,'bag-item-quantity')]"));

            SelectElementFromDropDown(qty, Math.Floor(noOfQuantity).ToString());


            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//button[@class='bag-item-edit-update']")));
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='bag-item-edit-update']")).Click();

            // webDriver.Quit();

        }



        private static void SelectElementFromDropDown(IWebElement ele, string text)
        {
            SelectElement select = new SelectElement(ele);
            select.SelectByText(text);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. Do you want to add the pair of shoes 200 times to the bag?

Comment: No, I want to add trainers till £200 is reached

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question properly, You want to use loop to add items until 200 limit is reached. In this case, you can simply adapt your code something like this

Assuming below line (first line) returns you total price:

```
string totalPrice = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='bag-subtotal-price']")).Text;
double total = Convert.ToDouble(totalPrice)       

    while(total > 200)
    {
         //code for adding items.
         //update total price
         total = Convert.ToDouble(webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='bag-subtotal-price']")).Text);          
    }
```